# Передача Sate сгенергрированному списку в React

Tags: reactjs

Мое клиенсткое приложение на React получает динамический список вопросов с сервера.
После чего я генерирую в JSX при помощи мэп список из вопросов,которые мне пришли и чекбоксы,для ответов на них.Получается несколько многоразовых компонентов.Теперь я хочу получить ответы на эти вопросы из чекбоксов,как мне передать State в эти многоазовые компоненты.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так передавал в динамический map.

```
class TableFiles extends Component {
    state = {
        line: [
            { name:'Документ', data: '17.05.2002', type:'Пустая папка',size: 15,id:1},
            { name:'Фаил', data: '17.05.2003', type:'Пустая папка',size: 15,id:2},
            { name:'текст', data: '17.05.2004', type:'Пустая папка',size: 15,id:3}
        ],
        DataCap: 300,
        NameCap: 300,
        SizeCap: 300,
        TypeCap: 300
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="TableFilesComponents">
                <div id="TFilesOverflow">
                    <Cap props={this.state}/>
                    { this.state.line.map((props, index)=> {
                        return(
                            <Line
                                key={index}
                                name={props.name}
                                data={props.data}
                                type={props.type}
                                size={props.size}
                                id={props.id}
                            />
                        )
                    }) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```